# Auto Skype call from outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, skype-for-business

Can we trigger an auto call from Skype?

If a mail has a specific subject line in outlook, a call has to be triggered from Skype

Comment: Are you refering to Skype for Consumer [=SfC] (often called skype) or Skype for Business [=SfB]? Keep noted that both are different products...

Comment: Thanks @BastianW . This is in reference to SfB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible ideas here:

1. In theory you could write an Outlook plugin which monitor the Mailbox and then trigger the needed action directly via the [SfB SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/apioverview).
2. You could also use the [Exchange Webservices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj536567(v=exchg.150).aspx) to monitor a mailbox and then trigger the needed action. Here are some starting points:

   - [Work with Exchange mailbox items by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx)
   - [Use UCWA and making an outgoing IM call and sending messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn756469.aspx)